# Large String Object in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, design-patterns

I have a SQLite database which has a table (of course) named Object. In my application, I need to access that table and all of its fields. I am able to query the database and get all of the information I want from a cursor with no issues. The problem comes with deciding what to do with the cursor next. Right now I am thinking of creating a class called Object and it will have fields for every column in the table which will be set by the query. This just seems so... inefficient. I'm not sure how to do this without needing to write out every column that is in the table for the object to use, which seems to violate DRY. Are there any better ways to do this?

My end goal is to be able to access every row in the table and get whatever information I want for that row. For example I will be using this to populate a ListView. If this is too ambiguous let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks!

Edit: I've found the library [db40](http://www.db4o.com/) and it seems to do what I want. The library seems to be kind of big though (40 mb) for a mobile application. Does anybody have experience with this? Everything I've read seems to indicate it is good. I'll post more if I find information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any better ways to do this?

This is very "wide" question and depends on personal requirements and what is for developer more comfortable. I'm using your idea that is for me the best one you can use.

Generally we can say you want to create `ORM` (object-relation mapping). It's very clean and efficient approach (my opinion). Of course sometimes is not the best solution to use `ORM` ( i never met with this case but heard about it). I almost always use my own defined `ORM` for sure it takes some time but results are significant against done frameworks.

Both have advantages and disadvantages. Own `ORM` has much more higher performance because it's designated and optimized for concrete solution (mainly queries etc.).

I suggest you to do what you mentioned `->` create object that will represent table in database with properties equal to columns. I'm using this in work and we never had problems with performance or too much battery consumption with our applications.

It's also much more safe if you'll show user some data not directly from database but "copies" in objects. Users can do whatever want with dislayed results (they can add some dangerous symbols and hacks) but now you can easily check this before you'll want to update database(s) with changes.

Your source-code looks good, another developer won't be lost in your code, everything will be clear and easy to do updates for future.

I provided you "my opinion" on this thing so hope it'll help you with make a decision.

Comment: Thanks, this pushed me in the right direction. I think I'm going to go with db4o for now.